# iPhone force orientation change to Portrait mode after dismissing custom navigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have a navigationController as rootViewController and it is Portrait only, down the workflow I am presenting custom navigationController as modal in Landscape mode. All this works, but when I dismiss presented navigationController in landscape mode then presenter/parent views are displayed in landscape. This happens only when device rotates, I have checked Plist and other places(VC orientation flag in storyboard) where its set as Portrait only.

Presented ViewController Modally has a custom NavigationController, where I am overriding -shouldAutorotate: to return NO, -supportedInterfaceOrientations: to return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft and -preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: to return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

VC layout required:

1. RootViewController - Portrait only
2. presentViewController - Landscape
3. RootViewController - Portrait, when dismiss of Landscape VC.

I have tried many approaches stated in stack overflow:

1. creating category for NavigationController which set as rootViewController
   and specifying orientation as portrait for
   -supportedInterfaceOrientations: and -preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:.
2. [UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:animated:]
3. Setting Orientation in dismiss completion handler.

etc

but non seems to be working, any idea's or help ?